# Select data by date and sum data - SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I'm coming from MySQL and trying to code T-SQL on SQL Server 2005, and I'm finding it completely different.

Here's what I want to do (using MySQL)

```
select sum(datapoint) as sum, date(mytimestamp) as date
from datalog
where datapoint = '27'
group by date
```

i.e. get a list of data summed and grouped by date.

Comment: what data? are you referring to datapoint?

Comment: What's the question?  What trouble are you having?  (i.e. Is it an error?  What's the specific message?)   Aside, I have a feeling it should be `group by mytimestamp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

converting to varchar is not a good solution, simply remove the timepart from your timestamp and group by it like this:

```
select sum(datapoint) as sum, dateadd(d, 0, datediff(d, 0, mytimestamp)) as date
from datalog
where datapoint = '27'
group by datediff(d, 0, mytimestamp)
```

Comment: This solution gives me the result, and can be sorted by date with the addition of "ORDER BY datediff(d, 0, mytimestamp)".  Thank you to all those that helped, I wouldn't have found it without you, and I had know idea working with dates could be so tricky in MS SQL.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Answer when sql server 2008 was tagged

```
select sum(datapoint) as [sum], CAST(mytimestamp AS DATE) as [date]
from datalog
where datapoint = '27'
group by CAST(mytimestamp AS DATE)
```

For SQL Server 2005

```
SELECT   CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), timestamp, 111) DATE, 
         SUM(datapoint) totalDatapoint
FROM     table1
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), timestamp, 111)
ORDER BY DATE ASC
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5bca3/1)

Comment: Msg 243, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Type DATE is not a defined system type.
Msg 243, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Type DATE is not a defined system type.

Comment: data type `DATE` should exists in sql server 2008.

Comment: My IT department just confirmed this database is SQL 2005, not 2008 like I thought.  Can you help with the same query for SQL 2005?

Comment: can you give sample record on this column, `mytimestamp`?

Comment: its a timestamp "2012-01-01 21:13:45.000" with column type "datetime"

Comment: @user1745767 how about this one? [Click this link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d0b2c/7)

Comment: "ORDER by date" does not make a difference.  It's not an error.  Is it because it is now a VARCHAR, that it can't be ordered by date?

Comment: @marc_s yep, the original question was tagged as sql server 2008 that's why my answer was with CASTing to `DATE`, but after several comments, he mentioned that he was using sql server 2005. :D

Comment: @JohnWoo: aha! :) Sorry, didn't see that

Comment: @marc_s by the way can you help us sort the date by timestamp, i think it will have another subquery to satisfy the OP [sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cd286/1) :D

Comment: @JohnWoo: can't you just add `ORDER BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), timestamp, 113)` and get the results you need?

Comment: @marc_s i think it will not work because it's already on VARCHAR format. hehe [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cd286/2)

Comment: @marc_s changing to 111 solves the problem.. hehe `yyyy/MM/dd`

Comment: @JohnWoo: GREAT ! I was going to suggest to select (and group by) the `timestamp`, too - once you do that, you can also use `ORDER BY timestamp` and get the proper ordering

Comment: Thanks so much for helping.  Your solution does work, but the resulting VARCHAR type for a date field, makes sorting sub-optimal (it requires the date be displayed in a alphanumeric order).  The accepted solution maintains the date as date, and provides the solution best.  Thanks again, I have learnt a lot about MS SQL.